# How to solve $M - EV - (EV)^T = 0$ against $E$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix equation:
$$M - EV - (EV)^T = 0$$
which i want to solve against $E$. Is this possible? How to do that?

Remarks: matrices are square, $E$, $M$ are symmetric, $V$ is invertibile.

Regards,
Marek

Comment: think first as an equation on $Y = EV$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write this equivalently as
$$
EV + (EV)^T = M.  
$$
Because the (linear) operator $E \mapsto EV + (EV)^T$ is not invertible, this equation will have infinitely many solutions.  In particular, we can always take $E = \frac 12 MV^{-1}$.  Indeed, plugging this $E$ in yields
$$
EV + (EV)^T = \frac 12 MV^{-1}V + (\frac 12 MV^{-1}V)^T = \frac 12 M + \frac 12 M^T = M
$$
As it turns out, every solution to this equation can be written in the form
$$
E = \frac 12 (M + S)V^{-1}
$$
where $S$ is skew symmetric, which is to say that $S$ satisfies $S^T = -S$.

---

Now, requiring that $E$ is symmetric amounts to requiring that
$$
[(M + S)V^{-1}]^T = (M + S)V^{-1} \implies\\
V^{-T}(M - S) = (M + S)V^{-1} \implies\\
V^{-T}S + SV^{-1} = V^{-T}M - MV^{-1}.
$$
In other words: there exists a symmetric solution $E$ if and only if the [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) (more specifically [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)) $V^{-T}S + SV^{-1} = V^{-T}M - MV^{-1}$ has a solution $S$ in which $S$ is also skew-symmetric. I don't see a way of simplifying this condition.

It is notable that if the eigenvalues of $V$ have all positive real part or negative real part, then there exists a unique solution $S$.  If the eigenvalues of $V$ have only negative real part, then this unique $S$ can be written explicitly as the integral
$$
S = \int_0^\infty e^{V^{-T}\tau}[V^{-T}M - MV^{-1}]e^{V^{-1}\tau} d\tau.
$$
This $S$ is necessarily skew-symmetric, which is to say that our original equation has a (unique) symmetric solution $E$ in this case.

---

Another approach: if we're looking specifically for a symmetric solution $E$, then we can rewrite the original equation as
$$
EV + V^TE^T = M \implies V^TE + EV = M.
$$
Now, if the eigenvalues of $V$ all have negative real parts, then this equation has a unique solution that can be written as
$$
E = \int_0^\infty e^{V^{T}\tau}\,M\,e^{V\tau} d\tau,
$$
which is necessarily a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Ok, but it should exist only one $E$ which is symmetric, isn't it? It seems the question transforms to: how to find $S$ for which $E$ is symmetric?

Comment: I missed that $E$ is supposed to be symmetric.  I don't think that we can necessarily guarantee that a symmetric solution $E$ exists, but I'll think about it and add something.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm enlightened now :) But... i think that the original equation is also a Lyapunov one and maybe we can write such integral directly for E?

Comment: Technically it isn't because the second $E$ is transposed.  However, since we're looking for a symmetric solution we can make it one.  I'll add something.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Cool. A final edit is necessary i think (correct me if not): V and V^T should be swapped in latest equation...

Comment: I believe that it is correct as written

Comment: I thought they should be swapped because (referring to Wikipedia notation) we have A=V^T and A^H=V.

Comment: @mrkwjc just like in the wikipedia formula, $A$ appears on the left  and $A^H$ on the right

Comment: Sure! I was blind, looking not seeing... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In one dimensional case
$$
M - EV - (EV)^T = M - 2EV = 0 \implies E = \frac{M}{2V}.
$$

So, maybe you would like to check if
$$
E = \frac{1}{2} MV^{-1}
$$
in general case?